# Why doesn't C#/.Net use the clone paradigm?

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

I was struck by how copying a collection object in C# can be quite cumbersome, especially if you want a deep copy. Is there a good design reason why .Net didn't go the Java clone() route, and is there some equivalent paradigm I've missed in C#/.Net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733571/why-doesnt-the-net-framework-provide-a-method-to-deep-copy-objects

Comment: Because Java's `clone()` is *not* a deep copy.

Comment: @svick you learn something new every day!

Comment: @John: What is "new"? Can you ever really learn something "new"? Perhaps you can discover something new, but surely you can only ever learn something that somebody else has already discovered, which is therefore not new. Perhaps "I didn't know that!" is more suitable... don't worry, just ignore me, I am in pedantic mode!

Comment: @musefan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom Ever hear of them? ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Of course... do you really think I didn't understand what John meant? I was merely "pulling his leg" as one might say

Comment: More deep cloning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025890/is-there-a-much-better-way-to-create-deep-and-shallow-clones-in-c/8026574#8026574

Comment: @musefan it is a new piece of information stored in my memory. So I think it's accurate ;)

Comment: THis should have been closed as a duplicate, not as not constructive, otherwise many of the duplicates should be closed too!

Comment: @John: Which duplicate are you talking about? You were asking "Why doesn't .net have XYZ?". A similar question has been closed as not constructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733571/why-doesnt-the-net-framework-provide-a-method-to-deep-copy-objects. All other links here are about what deep copying in C# actually is. Those are not duplicates of your question.

Comment: And another related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308803/why-is-cloning-in-net-so-difficult

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Shallow Copies**

For shallow copies, .NET offers [Object.MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx).

**Deep Copies**

For deep copies, Microsoft suggests to implement a custom `Copy` method. Deep copies require intricate knowledge about the class itself -- in fact, for a given class, it might even make sense to make multiple different types of deep copy. Thus, there is no pre-defined method or interface for this purpose.

**But what about the ICloneable interface?**

There is the [ICloneable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx), whose purpose might correspond roughly to Java's `Object.clone`. However, Microsoft [advises against its use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx), since it does not specify how shallow or deep the copy needs to be for the interface to be implemented correctly.

Comment: Another way of doing a deep clone for a SERIALIZABLE object is to simply serialize it and then deserialize that into a new object. It's very inefficient though, but it's fine if speed isn't an issue.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's much faster if you write your own deep copy code, see my link above.

Comment: Of course it's faster to write your own. That's why I said "It's very inefficient though, but it's fine if speed isn't an issue". :)