# C# strange Double ObservableCollection behaviour

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, observablecollection

Maybe I don't understand the ObservableCollection well enough. But as far as I knew it was similar to a normal list, but with event triggers so that you can react to changes.

So I have this Windows store app. And in this application I have a main BusinessModel class which is the main source for all data in my client application. This data will be updated when the server has made some changes elsewhere. In the future I'd like to have this class update the ViewModels for specific data updates etc.
So I also have a ViewModel class which contains, at least in my PoC's so far, a copy of that list (also in the near future this list will have an enriched version of the list).
Since it's a copy they should be both separate instances and have their own separate items.
However when I update the copy in the ViewModel, the BusinessModel version changes with it.
And vice versa.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Underneath you will find the classes and their functions:

```
//the BusinessModel Class
public class ModelStuff : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataObject> _modelStuff;
    public ObservableCollection<DataObject> modelStuff
    {
        get
        {
            return _modelStuff;
        }
        set
        {
            _modelStuff = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("modelStuff");
        }
    }

    private static ModelStuff businessModel;

    public static ModelStuff BusinessModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (businessModel == null)
            {
                businessModel = new ModelStuff();
            }
            return businessModel;
        }
    }


    public ModelStuff()
    {
        modelStuff = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();
        modelStuff.Add(new DataObject(0));
        modelStuff.Add(new DataObject(1));
        modelStuff.Add(new DataObject(2));
        modelStuff.Add(new DataObject(3));
        modelStuff.Add(new DataObject(4));
        modelStuff.Add(new DataObject(5));

    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

---

```
//the ViewModel class
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataObject> _visibleStuff;
    public ObservableCollection<DataObject> visibleStuff
    {
        get
        {
            return _visibleStuff;
        }
        set
        {
            _visibleStuff = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("visibleStuff");
        }
    }

    private static ViewModel tvm;

    public static ViewModel TVM
    {
        get
        {
            if (tvm == null)
            {
                tvm = new ViewModel();
            }
            return tvm;
        }
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        visibleStuff = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>(ModelStuff.BusinessModel.modelStuff.OrderBy(c => c.testNumber));
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

```
//the TestObjects
public class DataObject
{
    public int testNumber { get; set; }
    public String testStr { get; set; }

    public DataObject(int i)
    {
        testNumber = i;
        testStr = "testje";
    }

}
```

---

```
//A randomly placed button invokes this function when clicked.
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff here
    int i0 = ModelStuff.BusinessModel.modelStuff[0].testNumber;
    ViewModel.TVM.visibleStuff[0].testNumber = 100;
    int i1 = ModelStuff.BusinessModel.modelStuff[0].testNumber;
    //i1 has the value 100 in my logs! :S
}

//Second version but vice versa
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff here
    int i0 = ViewModel.TVM.visibleStuff[0].testNumber;
    ModelStuff.BusinessModel.modelStuff[0].testNumber = 100;
    int i1 = ViewModel.TVM.visibleStuff[0].testNumber;
    //i1 has the value 100 in my logs! :S
}
```

---

Where has my reasoning gone wrong?
Why is this happening?
And more importantly, how can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your line of code:

```
  visibleStuff = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>(ModelStuff.BusinessModel.modelStuff.OrderBy(c => c.testNumber));
```

is not making a copy of the underlying objects at all. It is adding the same DataObjects from the original list to a new ObservableCollection.

You need to clone the DataObjects individually and add them to the new collection. Something like this should do it:

```
 visibleStuff = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>(ModelStuff.BusinessModel.modelStuff.OrderBy(c => c.testNumber).Select(i => new DataObject(i.testNumber)));
```

Comment: Does this mean it copies a set of pointers to the new collection? When I read the msdn documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) it actually says "Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection<T> class that contains elements copied(!!) from the specified collection.".

Comment: The elements *are* copied. The elements are references! :)

Comment: To expand on my last comment, there's no (with caveats!) general way for performing a deep copy of an object. You have to write the code yourself (in the class), and invoke it explicity when you want a new object which is a deep copy of an existing object.

Comment: Ah! Well LINQ is still a bit confusing but I get it, and it works for my poc. Is there a way outside of LINQ to do the creation of the "new" objects so I can make this a bit more readable for my own sanity?

Comment: Also I thought the .Clone() function made a deep copy. Is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: Only if you choose to make your class implement the ICloneable interface, and implement the Clone() function yourself...

Comment: I guess that is worth it for my more complex objects in the future. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't use `ICloneable` if I were you though. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3712564/2609288